# In Perforce, how to unshelve change from one branch to another one?

Tags: perforce

I have two branches in Perforce, one is branchA another is branchB, in branchA I have a changelist contains several files, now I want to unshelve it to branchB, I use the following steps:

1. Change perforce config to branchA, shelve the files use "p4 shelve -c changelistA"
2. Change perforce config to branchB, create a new changelist "changelistB"
3. In Brunch B, unshelve the changes use "p4 unshelve -s changelistA -c changelistB -b branchB"

But it throws the error "No such file(s)." How to solve this issue?

Comment: Sounds like there are no files in the changelist that map through the branch spec.  If you add the following output to your question I might be able to help: (1) "p4 files @=changelistA" (2) "p4 branch -o branchB"

Answer (score 2):

You have to run the following commands:

> 1. p4 unshelve -s change_list_number -b your_destination_branch
> 2. p4 resolve ...

The first one bring the changes and the second one resolved any conflict

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a couple of releases ago (2014.1?) the ability to unshelve to another branch was introduced. From the shelved changelist, select *Unshelve* then select the *Map unshelved files* option (using Branch Mapping). Of course, this assumes you have a Branch Mapping spec set up.